# Can you have a tangent to the curve for a point which the function does not intersect?

Tags: calculus

The question I was given is to find the tangent to $f(x) = (x^4 - 2x + 8)^6$ at point: $(1,2)$

$f(x)$ does not pass through this point since $f(1) = 117649$.

Should I find the tangent for $(1,117649)$, and point out the error in the text, or should I find the tangent to the curve for point $(1,2)$ even though the function does not go through it.

Thank you,
Julian

Comment: It is possible to have a line that passes through the point (1,2) that is tangent to the given curve at some point(s) P .It is then obvious that P has different coordinates than (1,2) I doubt that this is easy to figure out. What you cannot do is take a derivative, plug in x=1 and use (1,2) to find an equation of the line assuming that it is a tangent to the curve because, as you indicated, (1,2) is not on the curve

Comment: Would you think that the question has an error?  Or this is some type of critical thinking exercise? I'm confused.

Comment: I don't know what level calculus course this question is from, but if this a chapter about learning derivatives, then I think there is a mistake in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the y-coordinate you get is a large number compared to the given 2, you should point out the error to your teacher.

Comment: Why is a large number indication of an error?!

Comment: I  meant different number. Large number  is not an indication of error. $ 1176499 \ne 2 $ is an indication of error, large or small.